# How to count frequency on an sorted linked list (numbers) Java

Tags: java, list, frequency, sorting

I have a linked list using nodes, also i have a method in which when you add a number the method sort them. so when i finish adding the numbers the output is a sorted list, the problem is that i have to count how many times a number repeats, so perhaps the node method that i have is this one:

```
 class Node {

    int value; 
    int freq;
    Node next;
} private Node root;
```

now I was trying this code in order to save the frequencies of a number comparing the sorted list values.

```
public void frequencies(){
    Node neew=root;
    Node current = neew.next;
    int x=0;
    while (neew!=null) {
        if(neew.value==current.value){ 
            neew.freq=x+1;       
        }
        else{
       neew=neew.next;
       current=current.next;
        }
    }

}
```

The code doesn't work (obviously) when i run the program the method loops.

I'm new in this stuff, so i don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong, can you guys help me?

Comment: Wait so are the `value`'s unique by node or can you have two nodes with the same `value`?

Comment: I can have 2 nodes with the same value

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can have two nodes with the same value.  In that case, I think the Node is the wrong place to store the frequency.  Why would the Node know the contents of its siblings?  Instead, you should ask the list this question.  A good data structure to store this in is a `Map`.  Have the Map key be the `Node.value` and the Map value be the frequency.

Iterate all your nodes then put `Map.value += 1` back into the map.  Then you can figure out the frequency of a value by saying: `Map.get(value);`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is not really a good way to go, try something like this

Keeping track of the freq when you are inserting the element.

2 cases to consider about:

If it's a new element, set freq = 0

else if it's a duplicated element, then when you find the first instance of that element that has the same value in the linked list, set the freq of the new element = old element.frequency + 1 and then keep on updating all the old element until you reach an element that has diff value (this is based on a sorted linked list which is what you are working with now)